# Matrix equation solving involving vectorization and Kronecker product

Tags: linear-algebra, least-squares, kronecker-product

I am looking an analytical solution for a least-squares solution of the following equation for $X$:

$(A \ (I_{J} \otimes X)) \  \textrm{vec}(X) = b, $

where $A \in \mathbb{R}^{I\times J^2}$, $I_J$ is the $\mathbb{R}^{J\times J}$ identity matrix, $X\in \mathbb{R}^{J\times K}$ and $b\in \mathbb{R}^{I}$.

Here $\textrm{vec}(\cdot)$ is the vectorization (flattening) operator. My approach so far consisted in taking the singular value decomposition (SVD) of $X$ and trying to proceed from there in terms of pseudo-inverse of $(A \ (I_{J} \otimes X))$, but I am stuck.

Comment: Is the vectorization [row-major or column-major](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order)?

Comment: It is probably worth noting that, assuming your vectorization was column-major, this equation can be written as
$$
A \operatorname{vec}(X^TX) = b.
$$
If $K < J$, then $X^TX$ is an arbitrary $K \times K$ positive semidefinite matrix, and if a numerical solution is desired then the problem of finding the best matrix $X^TX$ can be cast as a [semidefinite program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semidefinite_programming).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Collect both $X$ variables into the `vec()` term
$${
\def\A{A^{\bf+}}
\def\BR#1{\Big(#1\Big)}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\vc#1{\operatorname{vec}\LR{#1}}
\def\unvc#1{\operatorname{Unvec}\left(#1\right)}
A\LR{I\otimes X}\vc{X} \;=\; 
A\vc{X^TX} \;=\; b \\
}$$
and write the [least-squares solution](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse#Linear_least-squares) in terms of the pseudoinverse $\A,\,$ the nullspace projector
$P=\LR{I-\A A}\,$ and an arbitrary vector $w$
$$\eqalign{
\vc{X^TX} &= \LR{\A b + Pw} \;=\; f \\
X^TX &= \unvc{f} \;=\; F
}$$
where `Unvec()` reverses the action of `vec()` and $w$ is chosen to make $F$ symmetric.

The [Commutation matrix](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutation_matrix) $K$ is defined such that
$$\vc{M^T} = K \vc{M}$$
and it can be used to solve for the $w$ vector which will make $F$ symmetric
$$\eqalign{
f &= Kf \\
\LR{\A b + Pw} &= K\LR{\A b + Pw} \\
{\LR{I-K}P}\,w &= \LR{K-I}\A b \\
w &= \BR{\LR{I-K}\LR{I-\A A}}^{\bf+}\LR{K-I}\A b \\
}$$

The problem has been reduced to finding a symmetric SVD factorization of $F$ $\LR{{\rm i.e.\:}VDV^T},$ then dropping rows/cols associated with singular values of **zero** $\LR{V\to V_r,\:D\to D_r}.\;$
This is usually called the [Compact SVD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition#Compact_SVD)

The solution for $X$ can be expressed as
$$X = D_r^{1/2}\,V_r^T$$